Why is Spring batch so slow in executing steps
I wonder what causes in Spring batch job to have like 2 second delays between executing steps:
2024-12-06 15:42:18,975  INFO  o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherApplicationRunner - Running default command line with: []
2024-12-06 15:42:20,476  INFO  o.s.b.c.l.s.SimpleJobLauncher - Job: [SimpleJob: [name=annualReportJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{}]
2024-12-06 15:42:22,500  INFO  o.s.b.c.j.SimpleStepHandler - Executing step: [reportStep]

Logs don't show anything meaningful happening.
(I'm using H2 database for BatchDataSource - could the setting this up take so long)

Please enable debug logs and share them. The only thing that spring batch does between starting the job and running the first step is checking the state in the database (see if the step is a restart, initiailize meta-data, etc)
